# What causes an invalid file identifier in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, fopen

I have a MATLAB script that I could have sworn worked fine the last time I used it (a year ago).  Now, I get this error:

```
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
```

If I understand correctly, it is failing to find or open(?) a file specified elsewhere in the script.  Is this right? If so, what could cause it?

Comment: The error should always associate itself with a particular line of source code.  Use that to identify the problem.

Comment: Is it possible that your file isn't in your current working directory or in your matlab path somewhere?

Comment: I went back to the line the error pointed to, but I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: They all seem to be in the correct directories.

Comment: @nikipedia: The problem is that whatever line it is that's failing is using a file ID that is invalid.  Either you're not passing it a file ID that was created with `fopen`, or `fopen` failed.

Comment: can you give more details on what code you are actually running?

Answer (score 11):

`fid` (file identifier) is the output of `fopen`. It's an integer, but not related to the file permanently. You need to use `fopen` to get the `fid`. It seems to me that you are using incorrect `fid` (file identifier) in some file-related I/O command, such as `fread`, `fscanf` or `fclose`. Unsuccessful `fopen` gives `fid` of `-1`. For any valid normal file successful `fopen` will give `fid` that is `3` or greater integer.

However, without any code it's impossible to say where or what the bug or error is. You could use MATLAB debugger to single-step the code from relevant `fopen` (set breakpoint there and run your program) until the relevant `fclose` and see if `fid` (or whatever variable name you use for file identifier) or any data structure for your file identifiers (if have more than one file identifier in your code) changes in any point between relevant `fopen` and `fclose`.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem for my self by adding ***permission* option** to **fopen**.
As you see in http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html , fopen syntax is:

```
fileID = fopen(filename,permission)
```

Possible permissions, for example are:
 'r' (default) | 'w' | 'a' | 'r+' | 'w+' | 'a+' | ...

'r' – Open file for reading.

'w' – Open or create new file for writing. Discard existing contents, if any.

'a' – 
Open or create new file for writing. Append data to the end of the file.

'r+' – Open file for reading and writing.

'w+' – Open or create new file for reading and writing. Discard existing contents, if any.

'a+' – Open or create new file for reading and writing. Append data to the end of the file.

...

If I use fopen without permission option, or if I use 'r' (default) option, fopen will return -1, which is error. I success with this:

```
fid=fopen('tmp.txt', 'w');
fid=fopen('tmp.txt', 'a');
```

Comment: I'm using the permission 'rt', fid = fopen(offfullname,'rt'), but still getting fid=-1, and the same error "invalid file identifier" as the author is getting. It did use to work fine even a week ago!

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem. It turned out that the file I was trying to write was too large (I didn't have enough free space to accommodate it). However, the program didn't fail until the call to fclose. Very confusing!

Try freeing up some space, or writing a very small file, to test this diagnosis.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem when trying to open ASF toolbox demos. Running Matlab as an administrator(right-click to open) seemed to solve this issue for me.

Comment: Does not work for Ubuntu. Running with sudo but still having the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`fopen` can fail because MATLAB doesn't have the permissions to read/write the file you've specified.

Try opening a file in a location where you/MATLAB have all the rights (depending on your OS).

Answer (score 2):

I have used `fopen` with permission and the same error came out. However, I **started MATLAB as admin** and that took care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the file opened in excel and as a result fopen returned a -1. 
Took me forever to find such a trivial problem.

Answer (score 1):

It also happens when trying to create a file in a non-existent directory. Try `mkdir('folderName')` within MATLAB or just create the directory beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The path with a forward slash at the beginning can cause the same error.

```
filename = '/data/myfile.txt';
```

throws this error, while

```
filename = 'data/myfile.txt';
```

does not produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

For my situation, I have checked everything, but missed an easy step.

Please select "browse your folder" and browse for your current document location before you run your 'fopen' code.

[image]

Comment: HI and welcome to SO, consider making the [tour], and have a look into [answer].

Answer (score -3):

It also occurs when a script is trying to read beyond the end of the file.

Comment: No. Wrong. Sorry.