# Why I am suddently getting invalid file identifier error in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Code:

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('/home/username/Desktop/Old/MTP/tfcodev2p1/data/', '*.dat'));
```

There are 50 dat files in that folder. Weird thing is it was working perfectly alright till last night. Now I am suddenly getting this error. Error:

```
Error using fseek
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a
valid file identifier.

Error in getvar>get_convar (line 162)
fseek(f,8*mesh.n*(sim.nvars*t+VARS) , 'bof');

Error in getvar (line 82)
  data=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,VARS,t);

Error in realn (line 34)
       D1=getvar(list_of_files(i).name,sim,mesh,'rhoi',sim.nsaves);
```

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried putting my data in different folder but am still getting the same error.

Here is the code.
File realn.m:

```
list_of_files=dir(fullfile('/home/rishi/Desktop/Old/MTP/tfcodev2p1/data', '*.dat'));
%simulation details
%display(list_of_files.name);
hold off;
sim.tend=0.1;
sim.gamma=5.0/3.0;
sim.nsaves=1;
sim.nvars=20;
sim.dim=1;
sim.mass_ratio=1.0;
%mesh details
mesh.nx=100; %number of cells in x-direction
mesh.ny=1; %number of cells in y-direction
mesh.maxx=1.0;
mesh.maxy=0;
mesh.n=mesh.nx*mesh.ny;
mesh.x=linspace(0,mesh.maxx,mesh.nx);

N=100;
n=51;
tau=0.0001;
h=1/N;
lambda=tau/h;
mu=lambda/2;
uf=zeros(n,1);
uf1=zeros(n,1);
uf2=zeros(n,1);
phi=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    phi(i,1)=2*pi*i/N;    
end
for i=1:length(list_of_files)
   display(list_of_files(i).name)
       D1=getvar(list_of_files(i).name,sim,mesh,'rhoi',sim.nsaves);
       D2=getvar(list_of_files(i).name,sim,mesh,'rhoi',0);
   for j=1:N
       uf1(i,1)=uf1(i,1)+(D1(j)*exp(-1i*j*phi(i)));
       uf2(i,1)=uf2(i,1)+(D2(j)*exp(-1i*j*phi(i)));
   end
   uf1(i,1)=uf1(i,1)/100;
   uf2(i,1)=uf2(i,1)/100;
end
```

getvar.m

```
function data=getvar(fname,sim,mesh,V,t)
 NVARS=36;
 VARS=0;
 //switch upper(V)


 if (VARS<sim.nvars)
  data=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,VARS,t);
 elseif(VARS<NVARS)
  data=get_extravar(fname,sim,mesh,VARS,t);
 else
    display('WRONG Variable: Check function getvars()')
 end

function data=get_extravar(fname,sim,mesh,VARS,t)

switch VARS
    case {20}
        mxe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,6,t);
        data=-mxe/sim.mass_ratio;    
    case {21}
        mye=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,7,t);
        data=-mye/sim.mass_ratio;            
    case {22}
        mze=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,8,t);
        data=-mze/sim.mass_ratio;      
    case {23}
        mxi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,1,t);
        data=mxi; %assuume that m_i=1.0 
    case {24}
        myi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,2,t);
        data=myi; %assuume that m_i=1.0 
    case {25}
        mzi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,3,t);
        data=myi; %assuume that m_i=1.0 
    case {26}
        rhoe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,5,t);
        mxe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,6,t);
        data=mxe./rhoe;    
    case {27}
        rhoe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,5,t);
        mye=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,7,t);
        data=mye./rhoe;
    case {28}
        rhoe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,5,t);
        mze=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,8,t);
        data=mze./rhoe;
    case {29}
        rhoi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,0,t);
        mxi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,1,t);
        data=mxi./rhoi;
    case {30}
        rhoi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,0,t);
        myi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,2,t);
        data=myi./rhoi;
    case {31}
        rhoi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,0,t);
        mzi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,3,t);
        data=mzi./rhoi;     
    case {32}
        mxe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,6,t);
        mye=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,7,t);
        mze=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,8,t);
        data=sqrt(mxe.^2 + mye.^2 + mze.^2);
    case {33}
        mxi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,1,t);
        myi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,2,t);
        mzi=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,3,t);
        data=sqrt(mxi.^2 + myi.^2 + mzi.^2);
    case {34}
        mze=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,8,t);
        mzi=get_convar (fname,sim,mesh,3,t);
        data=abs(mzi-mze/sim.mass_ratio);   
   case {35}
       mxe=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,6,t);
       mye=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,7,t);
       mze=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,8,t);

        mxi=get_convar (fname,sim,mesh,1,t);
        myi=get_convar (fname,sim,mesh,2,t);
        mzi=get_convar (fname,sim,mesh,3,t);
        data=abs(mxi + myi + mzi-(mxe+mye+mze)/sim.mass_ratio);        
end

function data=get_convar(fname,sim,mesh,VARS,t)
f=fopen(fname,'r');
if (VARS<sim.nvars)
fseek(f,8*mesh.n*(sim.nvars*t+VARS) , 'bof');
if (sim.dim==1)
data=fread(f,[mesh.nx],'float64');
elseif(sim.dim==2)
    data=fread(f,[mesh.ny,mesh.nx],'float64');
else
     error('Check Dimension');
end
else
    error('Variable is out of range Use function get_extravar')
end
data=data';
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of the code that opens the file?

Comment: What happens when you manually open one of the `.dat` files?

Comment: It could be that permissions have been changed. Could be that the disk is full. Could be that you are using an old list; are you calling the `dir` directly before opening the files? You are POSITIVE that you have the EXACT directory name correct (e.g., capitalization is important on Linux)? Did you rename the dir, but not the string in the MATLAB function/script?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Hey, I have updated with the striped version of code. If you want I can share complete code too. It's an binary file and yes I am able to open it in sublime. I am absolutely sure about dir path because if directory path is wrong, I get another graph. I have tried restarting MATLAB, Ubuntu and also tried it in a MAC machine. It was working perfectly alright last night. I also checked this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606373/what-causes-an-invalid-file-identifier-in-matlab) but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: Does that path happen to be a network drive?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can say to help here (I cannot reproduce the problem, obviously) is to use this line from `help fopen`:

> [FID, MESSAGE] = FOPEN(FILENAME,...) returns a system dependent error 
>   message if the open is not successful.

Plant this in your `get_convar` function, and look at the `MESSAGE`. That should give you at least a hint as to what could be going on.

Please keep me posted, as I'm always looking for new ways in which file I/O can get messed up, to better ruggedize my own file reading/writing routines :)

Comment: I planted this in get_convar function and the message is No such file or directory and f also returns -1. This is weird because list_of_files struct is correctly displaying the file name and that means files are there. I have uploaded data and files here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/whw5xxizrebav49/stackOF.zip You just need to change path in line 1 of realn.m. If you can manage, please check it out. Thanks again.